# How can I display the icon of a WebView in QML?

Tags: qt, webkit, qml

I'm writing a simple web browser in QML with WebKit.

The `WebView` element has the property `icon` of type `pixmap` (QVariant::Pixmap). I want to display this icon in QML.

Before QML was stable, the `Image` element had the property `pixmap` of type `pixmap`, which was used by other people to display the icon of the `WebView` element.

But `Image.pixmap` has been removed.

How can I now set the icon on an Image element? Do I really have to work around this in C++ using the `QDeclarativeImageProvider`? What's the most straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QtWebkit3:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0


WebView {
    id: webview;
}
Image {
    source: webview.icon;
}
```

As the [icon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qml-qtwebkit3-webview.html#icon-prop) is provided as an URL, so directly usable by `Image` item.